# ¿Qué devuelve el "return nom.length()!=0;"?

Tags: java

Estoy viendo en un ejercicio, y tiene ese código:

```
public boolean asignarNombre(String nombre){
    if(nombre.length()==0){
        System.out.println("Error: cadena vacía");
        return false;
    }
    this.nombre = nombre;
    return nombre.length()!=0;
}
```

La parte que me causa intriga (que no sé cómo se desempeña porque no lo explica) es esta:

```
return nombre.length()!=0;
```

¿Cómo funciona esto?

Comment: La verdad es que tampoco parece tener mucho sentido. Si length() es igual a 0, se devuelve false un par de lineas más arriba (en el if), por lo que llegado a ese punto sólo tiene sentido devolver true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo primero que tienes que fijarte es la firma de la funcion, ya que de ahi sabras que tipo devuelve esa funcion.

un poco de teoria sobre firma de funcion:

> La signatura o firma de un método o una función define su entrada y su
>   salida. Incluye por lo menos el nombre de la función o método y el
>   número de sus parámetros. En algunos lenguajes de programación, puede
>   incluir el tipo que devuelve la función o el tipo de sus parámetros.

en este caso la funcion devuelve `boolean`

`public boolean asignarNombre(String nombre){`

> ahora tu duda: `return nombre.length()!=0;` ¿cómo funciona esto?

Significa si el tamano de `nombre` es diferente de cero que retorne  `true` en caso contrario devolvera `false`

ejemplo: aunque mi ejemplo es en javascript, en java sucede lo mismo!!!

```js
console.log("".length!=0);
console.log("hola".length!=0);
```

`

Answer (score 2):

Te va devolver un *Booleano*, `True` o `False`. En este caso, `True`, ya que primero se evalúa si el tamaño del nombre es igual a cero (`0`), por lo que ya sabemos, que si pasa ese `if`, devuelve `True`.

Answer (score 1):

Yo haría lo siguiente

```
public boolean asignarNombre(String nombre)
{
    this.nombre = nombre;
    boolean validar = true;
    if(nombre.length()==0){
        System.out.println("Error: cadena vacía");
        validar = false;
    }

    return validar;
}
```

Es más legible y se entiende mejor creo yo
A tu pregunta:
nombre.lenght()!=0 devuelve true si la cadena tiene contenido.

Comment: No hace lo mismo. En el caso de la pregunta original solo asigna `nombre` en caso de que la longitud sea diferente a cero, pero en el tuyo, lo asigna siempre. Al hacer el `return` en la mitad del código, quiebra el programa.

Comment: Sí, lo sé, el problema es que yo no soy partidario de que se vaya cortando el código a la mitad, prefiero tener un return y usar una variable de control qué me diga que hace el código.